# How to keep always on bluetooth discoverablity & if I'm setting it for 300 sec then it should not ask me permission to allow always?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

This code always ask me **permission** to put my **discoverability on for 300 sec !**

```
if (mBluetoothAdapter.getScanMode() != BluetoothAdapter.SCAN_MODE_CONNECTABLE_DISCOVERABLE) {
        Intent discoverableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
        discoverableIntent.putExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION, 300);
        startActivity(discoverableIntent);
    }
```

I just don't want that permission dialog or it should be continuously discoverable !!!

Comment: Please don't undo my tag edit. This question has nothing specifically to do with Android Studio (which is purely an IDE), but is about Android. Therefore the android-studio tag is inappropriate.

Comment: This was intended by the developer. Most likely for privacy concerns, or an attempt to mitigate malicious behavior.